# Who is the model for Callaghan in Big Hero 6?

Tags: character-motivation, inspiration, big-hero-6

**Background:**
Professor Callaghan is the head of the robotics program at the San Fransokyo Institute of Technology.

It is later revealed that

> he is also [Yokai](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Yokai), the villain of the movie.

He is described (decently, IMO) in the [Disney Wiki](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Yokai) as:

> Professor Callaghan was an aspiring man; a world-renowned scientist, praised for his innovations on the foundations of robotics, as well as the creation of Callaghan's Laws of Robotics. With such recognition and knowledge, Callaghan put himself to good use by teaching as the head professor at the San Fransokyo Institution of Technology, where he mentored such prodigies as the brilliant Tadashi Hamada, who admired him greatly.

About his innovation:

- Callaghan's "Laws of Robotics" sounds suspiciously like Asimov's Law of
  Robotics.
- The Callaghan-Catmul spline is also mentioned, though it is attributed to a developer at Pixar.  ([link](http://Hiro%20mentions%20that%20one%20of%20Callaghan's%20inventions%20is%20the%20Callaghan-Catmull%20Spline.%20The%20Catmull-Rom%20Spline%20is%20a%20mathematical%20construct%20used%20in%20computer%20modeling%20and%20animation%20co-invented%20by%20Pixar%20president%20Ed%20Catmull.))
- There is connection between the voice actor for Callaghan and the *I, Robot* creator Alfred Lanning.
- Hiro talks about the technology behind his killer bot, but Callaghan invented it.  Not only is he part of the graphics, and computer programs, but he is also working on the actuation.

Callaghan is a character whose opening is engineered around Ethos.  He is meant to conjure something noble, learned, and doing great engineering feats.

**Question:**

**What real person most closely represents the persona of what the Callaghan was meant to be, prior to the revelation of his secret?**

While I can think of Asimov, I'm not sure if he qualifies.  I'm wondering if the writer had a single real person in mind when making the character.

Professor Hathaway, done good, might be another option, though he is built around lasers.

Is there a real "Callaghan", or a single source of inspiration for him?  Who is he?  References?

Comment: Unless Pixar/Marvel have a definitive response to this, it's primarily opinion based....

Comment: Wow, this should really be overhauled for spoilers.

Comment: @phantom42, can you direct me to a style guide that tells me how to "overhaul for spoilers"?

Comment: Markdown help is [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/editing-help). There's been [a lot of discussion about spoilers on meta recently](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoilers), but we generally try to avoid giving away major plot reveals without the spoiler tag.

Comment: Here are some pretty horrific potentials, but they don't seem to be robot-centric.
https://www.cracked.com/article_17039_9-real-life-mad-scientists.html